# how to get value from a html using external javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have two javascript files, js1 and js2.
js1 is defined in index.jsp. and inside js1 i'm using js2. once i'm executing js2 i want to take some values from index.jsp. (js2 can't define in ndex.jsp file)
so,
How can i access html using this external js file (js2)

this is my index.jsp

```
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <span id="up"></span>test<br><br><span id="down"></span>
    <br><br>
    Time : <span id="foo"></span>
    <br><br>
    <div id="uid" >this is the value i want to access</div>
    <button onclick="start()">Start sync</button>
    </body>
```

this is js1.js

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('js2.js', { scope: '/login/' }).then(function(reg) {
    if(reg.installing) {
      console.log('Service worker installing');
    } else if(reg.waiting) {
      console.log('Service worker installed');
    } else if(reg.active) {
      console.log('Service worker active');
    }
    //setTimeout(refresh, 10000);
  }).catch(function(error){
      console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
  });
```

this is js2.js

```
var eventSource2 = new EventSource("HelloServlet");
eventSource2.addEventListener('down_vote',function(event){
    console.log("data from down" , event.data);
    var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('uid'); //this is not working
    var val = MyDiv1.innerHTML; //this is not working
    console.log(val + "ddddd 2"); //this is not working
    console.log("down");
});
```

Comment: is there any way to send "uid" value once i'm navigation js2 in js1 ?

Comment: What is `index`? I do not see that variable declared anywhere.

Comment: index is index.jsp file. not a variable

Comment: my mistake. it should be document

Answer (score 0):

There is a mystery variable `index`

```
var MyDiv1 = index.getElementById('uid'); //this is not working
```

should probably be

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('uid');
```

Comment: i tried that and it is not working. (i have used index by mistake. corrected it)

Answer (score 0):

You are including js1.js at the beggining of you main page, so it can't find the DOM elements of index.jsp

You should include js1.js at the end of index.jsp

or include it in document.ready() of index.jsp

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <span id="up"></span>test<br><br><span id="down"></span>
    <br><br>
    Time : <span id="foo"></span>
    <br><br>
    <div id="uid" >this is the value i want to access</div>
    <button onclick="start()">Start sync</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js1.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: yes. your are correct. but that doesn't help for my issue.
because i want that element vale in js2 not in js1.

Comment: Yes, but js2 will be loaded in the js1. so at first js1 will be loaded, then js2, then the remaining of main page (index.jsp). so js2 can't see the "uid" element in DOM tree.